# What are the general steps of showing that $\mathbb{R}P^5$ and $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ are not homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

What are the general steps of showing that $\mathbb{R}P^5$ and $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ are not homotopy equivalent?

Also, I know that I should use that $S^n$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and that  $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$ is homotopy equivalent to a 2-sheeted covering of $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$, but I do not know why, could anyone proof this for me or at least show it by drawing please?

And what is the importance of that $S^4$ is a retract of $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$? and what is the importance of the antipodal map and why we are sure that we have it?

And why $\pi_{4}$ is the homotopy group that will show this for me and not $\pi_{3}$ or $\pi_{5}$ or any other $\pi.$

If a detailed proof is given this will be greatly appreciated as I am stupid in Algebraic Topology.

**I need the answer without any cohomology thm.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, observe that if you take $S^4$ and glue to it by two antipodal points two copies of $S^5$ you will obtain $S^5\vee S^4 \vee S^5$. Indeed you can just contract path between these two antipodal points obtaining homotopy equivalent space.

If you understand this, then you can simply take a quotient space by the antipodal map on $S^4.$ It identifies two copies of $S^5$ and on $S^4$ gives $\mathbb{R}P^4$ (you can see this directly from the definition of $\mathbb{R}P^4$ as a set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^5$).

Thus $S^5\vee S^4 \vee S^5$ is indeed a 2-sheeted cover of $\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5.$

Now we only need to compute some homotopy invariant that differs on these two spaces. And as you've said we can take $\pi_4.$

To compute $\pi_4$ observe that it is the same as $\pi_4(S^5)$ (since it is its universal cover) and thus is zero (by [cellular approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem)). On the other hand $\pi_4(\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5)\cong\pi_4(S^5\vee S^4 \vee S^5)\cong\pi_4(S^4)\cong\mathbb{Z}.$ Where $\pi_4(\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5)\cong\pi_4(S^5\vee S^4 \vee S^5)$ because higher homotopy groups of covering space and base space are isomorphic. Next two equalities again follow from [cellular approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem). And the last equality is actually quite hard and requires [Freudenthal suspension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem). Thus we conclude that spaces are not homotopy equivalent.

As for your question of why we should take precisely $\pi_4$ and not some other homotopy group the answer is because we can compute it and it is different.

For example, $\pi_3$ of both spaces is trivial by [cellular approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem) for universal covering spaces. We can take $\pi_5$ and it will be different, but the computation is far more difficult. In fact, computing higher homotopy groups of a wedge of spaces is generally (and even for spheres) an incredibly hard problem see for example [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141030/loop-space-of-wedge-sum-of-spheres)

Comment: I did not get your first three paragraphs can you draw them?