# What are the current known homotopy groups of the figure eight?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory

I'm curious about the homotopy groups of $S^1 \lor S^1$ and more generally $S^n \lor S^n$. What is the current knowledge about them?

Comment: The first homotopy group of $S^1\vee S^1$ is easy by a certain theorem involving path connected intersections (don't recall the exact statement) - it should be isomorphic to the free group on two letters, given $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S^1 \vee S^1$ has all higher homotopy groups trivial: its universal cover is a tree, which is contractible.

For $S^n \vee S^n$ you are not so lucky. You can still algorithmically compute these homotopy groups using [Hilton's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141030) if you happen to know all relevant homotopy groups of spheres (nobody knows all homotopy groups of all spheres and algorithmic computation is not very good).